# Can't create bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I just created a Google Cloud Storage account.

I am logged in - and the 'New Bucket' button is 'greyed' out (that is a lighter red) - and I can't click it.

What is going on? I just want to create a bucket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I waited & refreshed the page and now it works.

It was probably taking time to provision or recognise that I'd added billing data (would have been nice if it told me this).